# изменения height на auto по кнопке у нескольких div

Tags: javascript, html

Есть документ, в которым при формировании добавляются div-блоки. Хотелось в каждый такой div-блок включить кнопку "Показать полностью", которая бы меняла высоту у блока, в котором она была нажата с фиксированного значения на auto.

С помощью .getElementById я это умею делать, но здесь я не могу заранее проставить уникальные идентификаторы блокам, так как их итоговое количество сформированное внешней системой неизвестно.

То есть структура, например такая

```js
function toggle() {

  var tBlock = document.getElementById("textblock");
  var tText = document.getElementById("text");

  if (tBlock.style.height === "100px" && tText.style.height === "60px") {
    tBlock.style.height = "auto";
    tText.style.height = "auto";
  } else {
    tBlock.style.height = "100px";
    tText.style.height = "60px";
  }
}
```

```css
.docText {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.docTextContent {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="docText" id="textblock">
  <div class="docTextContent" id="text">
    Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn" onclick="toggle()">Показать</button>
</div>

<div class="docText">
  <div class="docTextContent">
    Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Показать</button>
</div>

<div class="docText">
  <div class="docTextContent">
    Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Показать</button>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы кнопка работала не на id и раскрывала текст только у своего блока?

Comment: Нужен цикл, верно... Но не `id`, а `class` и уже по индексу элемента выбирать конкретный блок... А вообще не понятно, что именно  хочешь реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function toggle(obj) {

var parentElement = obj.parentElement;

var childElement = parentElement.firstElementChild;


if (parentElement.style.height === "100px" && childElement.style.height === "60px") {
    parentElement.style.height = "auto";
    childElement.style.height = "auto";
} else {
    parentElement.style.height = "100px";
    childElement.style.height = "60px";
}

}
```

```html
      <div class="docText">
        <div class="docTextContent">
          Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста
        </div>
        <button class="toggle_btn" onclick="toggle(this)">Показать</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="docText">
        <div class="docTextContent">
          Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста
        </div>
        <button class="toggle_btn" onclick="toggle(this)">Показать</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   
    $('.toggle_btn').on('click',function(even){
      $('.docTextContent',even.target.parentNode).toggleClass('hidden');
      
    });

});
```

```css
    .docText {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: green;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .docTextContent {
      height: 0px;
      width: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .hidden{
      height: 70px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 

    <div class="docText">
      <div class="docTextContent">
        Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много           текста Много текста
      </div>
      <button class="toggle_btn">Показать</button>
    </div>

    <div class="docText">
      <div class="docTextContent">
        Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много           текста Много текста Много текста
      </div>
      <button class="toggle_btn">Показать</button>
    </div>

    <div class="docText">
      <div class="docTextContent">
        Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много           текста Много текста Много текста
      </div>
      <button class="toggle_btn">Показать</button>
    </div>
```

Наслождайся

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) для выбора всех DOM-элементов соответствующих селектору. Этот метод стандартно реализован в классах `Element` и `HTMLDocument`. Он возвращает статический `NodeList`: DOM-коллекцию, а проще говоря - массивоподобный список узлов (элементов).

*Обратите внимание, что `NodeList` не является "настоящим" массивом - этот тип не наследует `Array` и его перебирающие методы (такие как `forEach`, `every`, `map`, и т.д.).*

Найденные элементы можно обойти в цикле, используя обычный оператор `for`, или [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

---

Для того чтобы кнопка скрывала свой родительский блок - можно получить этот блок через свойство `parentElement`, и назначить ему класс с CSS-стилями.

При написании обработчика через обычную (не стрелочную) функцию, `this` ссылается на владельца этого самого обработчика... а значит, выполнять поиск родительского элемента не требуется: достаточно написать `this.parentElement`.
Класс элементу легко и быстро добавляется через свойство `classList` и его метод `add` (но данном случае, больше подойдет переключения класса, методом `toggle`).

---

Ниже в спойлере пример кода, который демонстрирует вышенаписанное:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // копируем блок. это чисто для компактности примера кода
  cloneElmnt(document.querySelector('.doc-wrapper'), 2);
  
    // получаем все элементы кнопок, вешаем обработчик клика
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.doc-wrapper .toggle_btn');
  for (let btn of btns)
    btn.addEventListener('click', onToggleClick);
});

  // обработчик очень простой - переключаем класс, для применения CSS
function onToggleClick() {
  this.parentElement.classList.toggle('show');
}

function cloneElmnt(el, count) {
  while (count-- > 0)
    el.parentElement.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
body { font: 16px sans-serif; }

.container {
  height : 80px;
  padding: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.doc-text {
  width: 120px; height: 100%;
  background-color: #aea;
  text-align: center;
}

.doc-text-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 2em);  /* минус высота пространства под кнопку */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle_btn       { margin: 0.4em 0; }
.toggle_btn:after { content: 'Показать'; }

/* вот этот класс и описывает развернутый блок */
.show {
  height  : auto;
  overflow: visible;   /* отображение содержимого за пределами границ элемента */
  z-index : 10;        /* для отображения над элементами ниже контейнера */
  position: relative;  /* обеспечиваем контекст наложения (иначе z-order не будет работать) */
  
}

.show .toggle_btn:after { content: 'Скрыть'; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="doc-wrapper">
    <div class="doc-text">
      <div class="doc-text-content">
        Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста Много текста 
      </div>
      <button class="toggle_btn"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Безусловно, внедрение современных методик играет важную роль в формировании прогресса профессионального сообщества. Как уже неоднократно упомянуто, явные признаки победы институциализации могут быть смешаны с неуникальными данными до степени совершенной неузнаваемости, из-за чего возрастает их статус бесполезности.
```

Как Вы наверное заметили в примере, есть еще один похожий метод: `querySelector` (без "All"). Он работает аналогичным образом, за исключением того что возвращает не `NodeList`, а только один узел - первый из подходящих по селектору.

Comment: Это именно то, что нужно, но при попытке применить в основном проекте что-то идет не так. Кнопка меняет название, но на блок текста не оказывает влияния никакого. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что параметры css класса .show перекрываются более специфичным селектором?

Comment: Будьте внимательнее, я изменил разметку (добавил div-обертку) и имена классов (привел их к рекомендуемой нотации). То есть, если просто скопипастить код без изменений - работать не будет, естественно... исправляйте под свою разметку. `p.s.:` Перекрытие тоже возможно, конечно же.

Comment: Нашел причину, не заменил doc-wrapper на аналог в моем проекте. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Рад был помочь! :) Кстати, если Вам будет нужен вводный материал по современным возможностям JS, он хорошо и понятно изложен на http://learn.javascript.ru/ - очень рекомендую для ознакомления.